# Nested for-loop to check arraylist against another arraylist

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, nested

I have a master arraylist (called `filteredArrayList`, and I want to import another arraylist onto it(called `importArrayList`), filtering the values  and create a new `checkedArrayList`, to get the truly unique ones and then append the `checkedArrayList` finally to the master.

The issue with my code is that the import always imports all of the objects in the `importArrayList`, instead of actually doing the check against the current values.

```
ArrayList<Patient> checkedPatientList=new ArrayList<Patient>();
                mainloop:for(Patient imp:importPatientList){
                        for(Patient p: filteredPatientList){
                            if (imp.getpID()!=p.getpID()){
                                checkedPatientList.add(imp);
                                continue mainloop;


                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I have tried many things but failed, any ideas on what to do would be welcome.

Comment: Can you please provide the Patient class?

Comment: If you want unique values, wouldn´t a `Set` be a lot more usefull?

Comment: You'll have to explain further what you mean with "unique". Does unique for you mean that it's not the same Object (not the same reference) or does unique mean 2 Patients don't contain the same data?

Comment: your if / add is incorrect: it add, when just one ID is different.  See my code

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the uniqueness is handled. The .getpID() gets the unique ID of the patient, which is always unique (its based off hashcodes and I've tested it).

Answer (score 0):

your code is incorrect there:

```
for(Patient p: filteredPatientList){
                        if (imp.getpID()!=p.getpID()){
                            checkedPatientList.add(imp);
```

you have to check all checkedPatientList before importing.

A set is simpler and faster.

assuming

```
public class Patient
{
public String getpID()
    {
    return "XX";
    }
}



ArrayList<Patient> importPatientList=new ArrayList<Patient>();

ArrayList<Patient> checkedPatientList=new ArrayList<Patient>();


// Do a Set with ID
Set<String> unique_id=new HashSet<String>();

 for(Patient p: checkedPatientList)
     unique_id.add(p.getpID());


// every patient in imported if not already checked
for(Patient imp:importPatientList)
if (!unique_id.contains(imp.getpID()))
           checkedPatientList.add(imp);
```

Comment: +1 for being the only person who took the time to explain why the existing code was not working. I don't know who marked you down, but it would be polite if they could explain why.

Answer (score 0):

try this logic

```
for (String item : pinkList) {
    if (normalList.contains(item)) {
        duplicateList.add(item);
    } else {
        uniqueList.add(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
if (imp.getpID().equals(p.getpID())){
......
}
```

Now, I am assuming you have got your desired list of Patients and the name of that list is patients. Now what you need to do is assigning the list to a Set to make the collection unique.

```
Set<Patient> set = new HashSet<Patient>(patients);
```

If u can move just with the Set, its ok. But if u need a List again, do the following-

```
List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<Patient>(set);
```

Now the list contains all the unique patients.

Answer (score 0):

I got it in the end! Thank you all for your answers, really helped me.

If there is anything I learnt, it is that in nested for loops, be careful what you do before you enter within the loops!

```
boolean isunique=true;
                    for(Patient imp: importPatientList){                                                                            
                        for(Patient p: filteredPatientList){
                            if (imp.getpID()==p.getpID()){
                                isunique=false;
                                break;
                            }
                            else{
                                isunique=true;
                            }
                        }
                        if(isunique){
                            checkedPatientList.add(imp);
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way in my opinion is using Set. And then if you really need you can copy it`s content to new ArrayList.

```
Set filteredSet = new HashSet<>();
filteredSet.addAll(filteredPatientList);
filteredSet.addAll(importPatientList);
List checkedPatientList = new ArrayList<>(filteredSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you gave yourself is technically correct but if you just want to neaten it up a little bit with fewer lines of code then you might prefer something like this :

```
ArrayList<Patient> checkedPatientList=new ArrayList<Patient>();    

for(Patient imp : importPatientList) {
    boolean patientIsUnique = true;

    for(Patient p : filteredPatientList) {
        if (imp.getpID() == p.getpID()) {
            patientIsUnique = false;
        }                            
    }        
    if (patientIsUnique) {
        checkedPatientList.add(imp);
    }
}
```